# Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon

Tags: centos7, openldap

I'm trying start slapd service and I'm getting the following error after running `journalctl -xe` command.

```
Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 06 11:22:43 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
Jan 06 11:22:43 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.
Jan 06 11:22:43 scv-ldap01.sesame.local polkitd[4630]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:31319:24705667 (system bus name :1.1226, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, loc
Jan 06 11:23:35 scv-ldap01.sesame.local su[31373]: (to root) sesame on pts/0
Jan 06 11:23:35 scv-ldap01.sesame.local su[31373]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by sesame(uid=1000)
Jan 06 11:23:35 scv-ldap01.sesame.local dbus[4639]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehelper)
Jan 06 11:23:35 scv-ldap01.sesame.local dbus[4639]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Jan 06 11:23:46 scv-ldap01.sesame.local polkitd[4630]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:31416:24712191 (system bus name :1.1232 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/fr
Jan 06 11:23:46 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: Starting OpenLDAP Server Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has begun starting up.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31427]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31427]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapcat[31431]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31438]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31438]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31440]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31440]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31442]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local runuser[31442]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.44 (Oct 30 2018 23:14:27) $
                                                              mockbuild@x86-01.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.44/openldap-2.4.44/servers/slapd
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif"
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: slapd stopped.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit slapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit slapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local polkitd[4630]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:31416:24712191 (system bus name :1.1232, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, loc
lines 3143-3193/3193 (END)
```

Answer (score 2):

after many attempts

refer to https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=6945

thanks to @toracat

reinstall openldap related packages did fix it

```sh
yum reinstall openldap openldap-servers openldap-clients
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Jan 06 11:23:47 scv-ldap01.sesame.local slapd[31445]: main: TLS init def ctx failed: -1
```

Looks like some issues with parsing certificate/keys, grep for TLS (`grep tls -ir /etc/openldap/slapd.d/*` ) and make sure certs/keys are present and accessible to `slapd` user.

Answer (score 0):

The next lines show the error
*ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif"*

need to **make backup** and reconfigure the server with the next line

*sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd*

be careful because that remove all configuration, here put again the correct parameters

[steps how to](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1217040&seqNum=5)

Answer (score 0):

I started slapd successfully, after create SSL cert,key & placed the file in /etc/pki/tls/certs/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).